# how do i create a login screen that allows for a common password to be entered but after the 3 threes the program must close (Java )

Tags: java, authentication

Information needed 3 tries then program closes.
The same password is used for every user.
The password is set too password = 12345678.
User data is extracted from a GUI component

Code I've tried:

```
String password = "12345678";
    
String userInput = String.valueOf(jPasswordField1.getPassword()); 
int length = userInput.length(); 
if (userInput.equals(password)) { 
    this.dispose(); 
    new INPUT().setVisible(true); 
} 
else if (!userInput.equals(password)) { 
    if (length > 9) { 
        lblValid.setText("To many characters"); 
        tries++; 
    } 
    else if (length < 8) { 
        lblValid.setText("To little characters"); 
        tries++; 
    } 
} 
if (tries == 3) { 
    System.exit(0); 
}
```

Comment: You should show us what you've attempted so far and what problem you are currently having. You must attempt to do some research. Please read "How to ask a good question" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 'code' String userInput = jPasswordField1.getText();
int length = userInput.length();
     if (userInput == password) 
     {
       this.dispose();
       new INPUT().setVisible(true);
     }
     else if (userInput != password) 
     {
        if (length > 9)
          {
           lblValid.setText("To many characters");
           tries++;
          }
           else if (length < 8)
           {
            lblValid.setText("To little characters");
            tries++; 
           }
      }
 if (tries == 3) 
 {
   System.exit(0);
}

Comment: sorry i honestly don't know what too do

Comment: Please paste your code into the question. It is unreadable in the comment. Also, comments are sometimes deleted.

Comment: @dylon_gon_ You are not comparing strings properly

Comment: what should i do

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scanner along with a while loop to achieve it:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tries=0;
    String password = "asdf123";//DO NOT USE THIS PASSWORD
    while(tries<3) {
        System.out.print("\nEnter password: ");
        String passwordattempt = scanner.nextLine();
        if(!passwordattempt.equals(password)) {
            System.out.println("Wrong password");
            tries++;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Correct");
            break;
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
```